# xpath expression to select the child nodes of a parent node having a specific string as text

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to write an xpath expression which checks if an Entity  supports 'create' Operation.
This is the codeI am using :

String line would have entity names without underscore like 'TciProfile' in this case.

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("entity name: "+line);
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath1 = factory.newXPath();

         XPathExpression expr = xpath1.compile("//Entity[matches(Name,'" +line+ "') and .//Operation/Name='create']");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList res = (NodeList) result;
        System.out.println("NodeList size: " + res.getLength());
```

where variable line in this case will be `TciProfile`.

But this expression reruns a `null` value when evaluated.

Could someone tell me what am i doing wrong here ??

```
<Entity>
<Name>TCI_Profile|TciProfile</Name>
<AttributeList>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
        <Type>string|string</Type>
        <Range>0-23</Range>
        <Default>null</Default>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name>Description|description</Name>
        <Type>string|string</Type>
        <Range>0-199</Range>
        <Default>null</Default>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeList>
<KeyAttributeNameList>
    <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
</KeyAttributeNameList>
<OperationList>
    <Operation>
        <Name>show|retrieve</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
            <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
            <Name>Description|description</Name>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
    <Operation>
        <Name>create</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Description|description</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
    <Operation>
        <Name>find|getNextItems</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>optional/searchable</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
            <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
    <Operation>
        <Name>delete</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
    <Operation>
        <Name>put</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Description|description</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
    <Operation>
        <Name>update</Name>
        <RequestAttributeList>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Tci_Profile_Id|tciProfileId</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
            <RequestAttribute>
                <Name>Description|description</Name>
                <Flag>required</Flag>
            </RequestAttribute>
        </RequestAttributeList>
        <ResponseAttributeNameList>
        </ResponseAttributeNameList>
    </Operation>
</OperationList>
```

Comment: That doesn't begin to compile due to missing quotes...  Please post the _real_ code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
//Entity[matches(Name,'TciProfile') and .//Operation/Name='create']
```

Tested in Oxygen/XML, this returns the Entity node(s) that satisfy both conditions

Comment: When i use a variable instead of the string, it returns null.

          //Entity[matches(Name,'" +line+ "') and .//Operation/Name='create']
where line is TciProfile.

Comment: Create the XPath expression in a String and print it before using it to create the `XPathExpression` object.